# Can't find a way to get Seller's UserID or Store by ItemID in EbayAPI

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I was trying to get the UserID by ItemID (which I got from a `findItemsByKeywords`) on EbayAPI, so I could use the UserID to use GetSellerList. Sadly, couldn't find a way to make it work, since the UserID is anonymized.

Are there any alternatives to using an UserID and making the `GetSellerList` call to get a particular user's items list?

Answer (score 0):

Haha, for anyone else, I got bamboozled between the high bidder and the seller! Check carefully the XML you get!